# How build Android Background Service proper way

Tags: android, service

I want to build a android background service for check data from MySQL data base.Normally I doing extend from Service class and when start the app,I run service using startService() method.But problem is if i remove the app from task manager,the service is also stopped.Another thing is I want to start this service when start the device,I mean beginning.How I implement this.Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you kill your app, the service is going to restart, not be removed. You can decrale the flag to define the break point when service restart, and write some 'if' 'else' to do thing after this break point.
 And if you want to start serivce when start the device, just create the broadcastReceive call 'autoStart'.
 In Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".autoStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and in autoStart class:

```
 public class autoStart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,yourservice.class);
        ctx.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }
}
```

When started device, system will detect on boot completed, and call this autoStart BroadcastReceive, and call your service from here